# Конвертация даты в ГГ-ММ-ДД

Tags: javascript, дата

Есть date; возвращает дату элемента в формате ДД.ММ.ГГ (26.02.2021), подскажите пожалуйста как его сконвертировать на ГГ-ММ-ДД (2021-02-26), на JS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
console.log( format("26.02.2021") );
console.log( format("26.02.2021").slice(2) );

function format(date) {
  return date.split(".").reverse().join("-");
}
```

`"26.02.2021".split(".")` разбивает строку на массив строк `["26", "02", "2021"]`,

`.reverse()` переворачивает элементы массива,

`.join()` собирает строку из массива, расставляя между элементами переданный разделитель.

Comment: Благодарю, работает!

Comment: @Влад, для коллекции: `'26.02.2021'.replace(/(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4})/, '$3-$2-$1');`

Comment: Благодарю, а можно из дня сделать минус 1?

Comment: @Влад А если это 1-е марта, Будет 28 или 29 февраля?) Руками такое муторно делать, будет удобнее изначально создать объект `new Date(y, m, d)`, оттуда отнять день и изначально выдать корректную дату на форматирование.

Comment: @Deonis а можно из $1 вычесть 1 день?

Comment: @Влад, вам уже *OPTIMUS PRIME* намекнул, почему обычная арифметика с датами далеко не всегда работает и в какую сторону нужно двигаться, чтобы решить ваш второй вопрос. Посмотрите описание метода [.setDate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate)